# Bash cannot echo $(hostname) embedded in variable

Tags: bash, echo, hostname

If I echo a string which contains the **$(hostname)** command, then it works fine. For example, run in terminal:

```
echo "http://$(hostname)/main.html"
http://artur/main.html
```

But if I get that string from a file (previously doing cat to a variable) when I try to print with echo, it does not works:

```
$ cat site
http://$(hostname)/main.html
$ mysite=$(cat site)
$ echo $mysite
http://$(hostname)/main.html
```

What am I doing wrong? Any idea?

Comment: `$(cat site)` can be replaced with `$(< site)`.

Answer (score 10):

The shell performs *variable expansion* and the shell performs *command substitution* but it does not do them recursively:

1. The result of a *variable expansion* will **not** be subjected to any further *variable expansion* or *command substitution*.
2. The result of a *command substitution* will **not** be subjected to any further *variable expansion* or *command substitution*.

This is a good thing because, if it was done recursively, there would be all manor of unexpected results and security issues.

One solution is to use `eval`.  This is a generally dangerous approach and should be regarded as [a last resort.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048)

The safe solution is to rethink what you want.  In particular, when do you want `hostname` evaluated?  Should it be evaluated before the `site` file is created?  Or, should it be evaluated when the code is finally run?  The latter appears to be what you want.

If that is the case, consider this approach.  Put `%s` in the `site` file where you want the host name to go:

```
$ cat site
http://%s/main.html
```

When you read the `site` file, use `printf` to substitute in the host name:

```
$ mysite=$(printf "$(cat site)" "$(hostname)")
$ echo "$mysite"
http://artur/main.html
```

With bash, an alternative for the form for the above is:

```
$ printf -v mysite "$(< site)" "$HOSTNAME"
$ echo "$mysite"
http://artur/main.html
```

Comment: In Bash, you can (mostly) use the variable `HOSTNAME` instead of the command `hostname`: `printf -v mysite "$(< site)" "$HOSTNAME"`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Good point.  Answer updated to use `HOSTNAME` for the bash solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the placeholder 'hostname' to be replaced by actual hostname, you could use either of these methods:

With your existing `site` file:

```
$ cat site
http://$(hostname)/main.html
$ mysite=$(sed 's|\$(hostname)|'"$(hostname)"'|g' site) # or
$ mysite=$(awk '{print gensub("\\$\\(hostname\\)",hostname,"g", $0);}' "hostname=$(hostname)" site)
$ # Note: Above `sed` based method has risk of shell injection. `awk` option is safer.
$ echo "$mysite"
http://artur/main.html
```

Or if you don't mind changing your `site` file contents, there is a tool, which is typically used for such purposes - to replace placeholders by actual values: [`m4 - macro processor`](http://www.unix.com/man-page/linux/1/m4/)

```
$ cat site
http://HOSTNAME/main.html
$ # HOSTNAME is the placeholder here; can be any identifier string.
$ mysite=$(m4 -D "HOSTNAME=$(hostname)" site)
$ echo "$mysite"
http://artur/main.html
```